# How to change the height of a responsive iFrame?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, responsive-design

The height of my iFrame is too short but if I change it from 100% it doesn't change the container it just changes the scrolling height.

How would I make my container taller?

This is Bootstrap framework and to make the iFrame responsive I need certain code, if I change the height the scrolling height of the iFrame changes.

```html
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Change the iFrame container height please

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use (℅ )for height, you should use min-height and max- height property with( PX )and then check the responsive if you want!

Comment: I've seen several websites that use 100% for responsive iFrames plus when I change it for px it messes up..

Comment: just tested it, turning the 100% into px property it doesnt work

Comment: I tested it, its OK for me!

Comment: I tested 

<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>

With height :100% and height:500px;
Are you sure your style is set? Use
 !important end of the style

Comment: Il try that now thank you! So Height 100% doesn't interfere?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a fix by adding !important on the height attribute forthe container.

```css
.iframe-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
height: 600px !important;
}

.iframe-container iframe {
   border: 0;
   height: 100%; 
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```